# CSS - Overflow not working as expected

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align my span text with my `<a>` tags. I tried using `vertical-align: middle;` on the `<a>` tags, but that doesn't work.

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: Arial;
 font-weight: bold;
}

nav {
 background-color: #298fca;
 overflow: hidden;
 list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

a {
 padding: 10px 25px;
 font-size: 20px;
 margin: 10px;
 border: 1px solid #61bd4f;
 background-color: #61bd4f;
 color: white;
 border-radius: 5px;
 float: right;
 text-decoration: none;
}

span {
 color: white;
 background-color: #298fca;
 overflow: auto;
 font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <span>Test</span>
  <a href="register.php">Register</a>
  <a href="login.php">Login</a>
 </nav>
```

Comment: The vertical align property works for elements with display as  inline or table-cell

Comment: can u have a set height on the nav? Or can u run flexbox?

Comment: alter your expectations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `vertical-align` property works for elements as `inline-level` or `table-cell`

I've commented out unecessary properties from your CSS

Add this to your existing CSS

```
nav {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

span {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: Arial;
 font-weight: bold;
}

nav {
 background-color: #298fca;
 /*overflow: hidden;*/
 list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
    /*vertical-align: middle;*/
  
   display: table;
   width: 100%;
}

a {
 padding: 10px 25px;
 font-size: 20px;
 margin: 10px;
 border: 1px solid #61bd4f;
 background-color: #61bd4f;
 color: white;
 border-radius: 5px;
 float: right;
 text-decoration: none;
}

span {
 color: white;
 background-color: #298fca;
 /*overflow: auto;*/
 font-size: 30px;
  
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <span>Test</span>
    <a href="register.php">Register</a>
    <a href="login.php">Login</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

A workaround will be using line-height

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: Arial;
 font-weight: bold;
}

nav {
 background-color: #298fca;
 overflow: hidden;
 list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

a {
 padding: 10px 25px;
 font-size: 20px;
 margin: 10px;
 border: 1px solid #61bd4f;
 background-color: #61bd4f;
 color: white;
 border-radius: 5px;
 float: right;
 text-decoration: none;
}

span {
 color: white;
 background-color: #298fca;
 overflow: auto;
 font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 2.1;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <span>Test</span>
  <a href="register.php">Register</a>
  <a href="login.php">Login</a>
 </nav>
```